# Simple HTML Code for Horiz Bar doesn't work for Google Sites

Tags: html

I"m trying to add a piece of HTML code to my Google Sites HTML box. I am new to this, please bear with me! I've tried the code out on some HTML test sites, and it works fine with no errors. Once I copy/paste into my Google sites HTML box, it gives me an error as follows:

```
6+1 - 2: Expected <Selector> not <
```

My frankenstein (pieced together crudely by myself) html is as follows:

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
Body {Background-Color:#;}
#Header {background-color:#CCC;
            Width: 100%;
                            }

<div style="overflow:auto”


</style>
<Div ID="Header">
<p>
<img src=

http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/gmail-logo-icon.png?w=300
align="center">...some text...
</p>

</Div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody shed some light on why it doesn't work in the Google Sites HTML Box?? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Also remove the <div style="overflow:auto” in your style tag and read about HTML/CSS more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will try help you.

1. Always format code. It's better for you and others to read it later.
2. I don't know which `doctype` you use but u missing to close `img` tag.
3. Try using stylesheets files instead of writing line css.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {background-color:#;} /*<----- missing color*/
    #Header {
        background-color:#CCC;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* <div style="overflow:auto” <----------- it shouldn't be here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Header">
    <p>
        <img src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/gmail-logo-icon.png?w=300" align="center" />...some text...
    </p>
</div>
</body>
```

If you have any question just ask. I will try help you If I would know.

Comment: Thanks guys! I at least got the thing to show with Woo's code, still can't get the horizontal bar to appear in color, but it's ok for now! All the functionality is there, that's what's most important. However, if you do come across a reason that Google Sites doesn't show it, please let me know!! Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide us link to your test page or put code on jsFidlle? I can help you if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your style in the header.

Also you are missing a '>' after your div. Even though it shouldn't be there to begin with, that's why your code is yielding error messages.